# Vector Calculus-Integral of differential vector.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

While reading the mathematical introduction to a physics textbook, I came across a problem that asserted that:
$$ \int dA$$  (where A is a plane surface)
is a vector with a direction perpendicular to a surface A. In my studies of vector calculus, I remember learning that the integration of a vector (unless its a vector valued function) is not possible. However, now I realize that the above equation should have a direction as the area of A does indeed have a direction.

My question is why don't all integrals give vector results? The differentials all appear to be vectors (as shown above) and thus shouldn't all integrals give vectors?

Comment: it would be more accurately rendered as $\hat{\mathbf{n} }\,dA$, where $\hat{\mathbf {n}}$ is the normal to the surface. This is where the vector comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an abuse of notation. In general $\int d\vec A$ is a vector quantity and $\int dA$ is a scalar. Some authors use $dA$ as a vector quantity, but you should be able to get this information from the context.

Comment: That makes sense, but how exactly would you carry out the integration of a vector quantity. I have only ever seen the integration of a dot product of vectors or a vector valued function. Would you treat dA(vector) as dA(scalar) and make the result a vector? Or would you have to find such a vector valued function?

Comment: You would need to project the $d\vec A$ vector along the directions in the space, and calculate the integrals independently:$$\int d\vec A=\left(\int \hat x d\vec A, \int \hat y d\vec A, \int \hat z d\vec A\right)$$